# Blender won't start. Installed in Fedora 28

Tags: installation

No problem with the installation. I start the application by clicking on its icon and it seems to try but a window with glitches appears. I'm afraid it's something from the graphics card.
I installed it on a 2008 Mac pro with fedora 28. All the other applications I've tried work well and the graphics go well with everything. The only problem is with Blender.
How can it be solved?
My chart: ATI RV 630 XT Radeon HD 2600 XT

Comment: Just make be sure, is your GPU driver the latest version?

Comment: Start it by typing `blender` + Enter in a terminal, then you can see any error message that it's giving you.

Comment: Try using a standalone version from blender.org and not one from repos.

Comment: if I run it from the terminal, it answers this: "[salvalnx@localhost ~]$ blender
: CommandLine Error: Option 'enable-value-profiling' registered more than once!
LLVM ERROR: inconsistency in registered CommandLine options
"

Comment: As root: [root@localhost salvalnx]# blender
No protocol specified
Unable to open a display
Aborted (`core' generado)
"

Comment: Running a downloaded Blender does the same thing. Display with Glitch and start is canceled.   I'm afraid it's the graph but it only happens with this application.